# How to say job offer in Mandarin/Cantonese?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

Google Translate says **job offer** is 工作機會.

This doesn't feel right.

How do you say job offer in Cantonese and Mandarin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Job offer' is a noun.  It means 工作提案 in literal sense

**聘用提案** (hiring offer) world be a better Chinese counterpart

you can also use a more literary term '邀聘' [invite to a job(v); job invitation (n)]

Example:

> 大飯店開張要大量招聘各部門員工
>
> The opening of a grand hotel requires hiring of a large number of employees in various departments.

*(招聘 means calling for people to apply for the positions)*

> 而行政總廚一職我想邀請XX酒店的大廚擔任
>
> And I want to invite the head chef of XX Hotel to serve as the executive chef.

*(邀請 means 'to invite')*

> 但XX酒店的大廚對這個**邀聘**看法又如何？
>
> But how the head chef of XX Hotel thinks of this  **job invitation**?

*邀聘 as a verb means 'invite to a job' (邀請受聘)*

*邀聘 as a noun means 'hiring invitation' (聘用邀請)*

*(This job is only offered to you, we are not opening this position to the public)*

> 最後XX酒店的大廚接受了我們的**邀聘**
>
> Finally, the head chef of XX Hotel accepted our **job invitation**
>
> 最後XX酒店的大廚接受了我們的**聘用提案**
>
> Finally, the head chef of XX Hotel accepted our **job offer**

side note:

In Cantonese, 'hotel' is '酒店' , 'head chef' is 大廚 or 頭廚

In Mandarin, 'hotel' is '飯店' , head chef' is 總廚

Answer (score 3):

colloquially most people just say "offer" instead of trying to translate it. In formal documents it may say 录用信/录用函.

Comment: 录用信/录用函 means "hiring confirmation letter" If you applied for a job, you will either get a "hiring confirmation letter" or "rejection letter"